# How to show json format output on view when returned as an ActionResult Object in MVC?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**HomeController.cs**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestExample()
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> result = await myClient.For<Customer>().FindEntriesAsync();
    return View(result);
}
```

which will return me a List of Customer data. I want to show this data in `json` format on the View.

I tried like this:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

But I do not have the `Model` :(

Comment: What do you mean by `I do not have Model`? Is it empty?

Comment: What do you mean _I do not have Model_? The value of `var model` will contain the collection of `Customer` as a javascript array. What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you have forgotten to specify the type of your model in your View.

You need to have the `@model type` line in the beginning of your View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Customer> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
IEnumerable<Customer> result = await myClient.For<Customer>().FindEntriesAsync();         
ViewBag.Customers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

And in the view

```
var customers = @Html.Raw((string)ViewBag.Customers);
```

Comment: can i use direct conversion in view? instead use ViewBag

Comment: No improvement whatsoever.